# LINQ calling a method inside Select passing as parameter the selected item in linq

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to call method in linq query select part of property. is it possible to call a method in inside select query.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oI8y.png)

Comment: It would be much nices if you don't attach screenshots but write the code actually here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: please write your code

2: it can not be done because you're function is in c# and the query wants to run in sql.

you have 3 options:

a: try quantify CancleInvoice after your query in c#

b: use simple codes that ef can translate to sql code

b: build your function in sql server and then you can use it in ef